# how to get a video's duration in both php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video, duration

I want to get the duration of the video while user uploading the video.
I dont want to put the video tag in html.
I want the getting video duration code in both php and javascript or jquery.
thank you

Comment: **(1)** _"I dont want to put the video tag in html."_ Why not? Also you can create a video object in Javascript and have it load the user-selected video (doing a `video.load()` will decode the compressed video data to extract metadata like duration). Video can be invisible on the page.  **(2)** Not obvious what your current code is doing. Is the FileReader API involved? Are you getting bytes into an Array or just getting a Data URL (is a pointer to some file)? **(3)** Why is the user's video being "uploaded" into the web page but then not used in a video tag?

Answer (score -1):

In HTML5 you can simply get a video's duration in Javascript with the duration function. For example:

```
document.getElementById("video").duration();
```

Do check if it has loaded already by using the following: (else you get an error)

```
document.getElementById("video").currentTime > 0;
```

Comment: Quote: 'I want to get the duration of the video while user uploading the video'

Comment: Oh, woops. In my experience checking the duration while uploading isn't possible. Hopefully someone can prove that wrong? With URL.createObjectURL() you can probably get the info -after- it's done uploading, but before it's loaded.